# CSS multi-column: not all columns filled

Tags: css, multiple-columns

For an overview of all products I have each product as an list item. The ul I gave the mulit-column attribut and set the column-count to 5. I have 9 products, so there should be 5 items in the first row and 4 in the second - right?

```
ul.products{
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-gap: 30px;
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
    column-count: 5;
    column-gap: 30px;
}
```

The problem is that only 3 columns are filled. In the fourth and fifth are no products/list-items. I made a jsfiddle so you can see this and experiment: http://jsfiddle.net/oliverspies/W8PE9/2/

Why are the list-items arranged like this? What do I have to do to get all columns filled?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W8PE9/20/ ...Just added `height: 400` for `products`

Comment: Note: The column-count property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Comment: But with a fixed height a lot of flexibility gets lost. I have to use jQuery to calculate the needed height, but this is the best solution so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W8PE9/20/)

```
.products{
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Note: The column-count property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `display:inline-block` on `.products li` you will have your 5 columns.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W8PE9/8/)**

Comment: But then the all the li have to have the same height - otherwise part of the li could be splitted on two columns.